# Use Monte Carlo methods to approximate the probability that a line joining 2 random points in a ring 1 < x 2 + y 2 < 4 does not cross the inner circle

Tags: r, probability, monte-carlo

My method so far is to fix one point (polar coordinates (r,0)) and then generate a large number of points (polar coordinates (r,a))) in the ring and accept these points if their angle 'a' satisfies theta < a < 2pi-theta where theta equals arcsin(1/r) however I am unsure if this is correct and if so how to programme this using R

Comment: Won't this depend on both values of r?  Does "accept"ing the point mean the segment _does_ cross the inner circle?  Also, keep in mind that the uniform distribution on polar coordinates is not geometrically uniform over the annulus.

Comment: Do you mean "line" or "line segment"?  The distinction is crucial.

Comment: This similar to Bertrand's paradox about the length of a "random" chord of a circle. We get different answers if the "random chord" is defined via (i) picking a fixed point on the circle and choosing the other point uniformly distributed on the circumference of the circle, or (ii) choosing a point uniformly distributed on a diameter of the circle and defining the random chord as the one through that point that has the diameter as the perpendicular bisector or (iii) choose a random point uniformly distributed inside the circle and define the random chord as the one whose midpoint is the point.

Comment: @Dilip Because it is conventionally understood that a "random" selection of any point from a set of positive measure has a *uniform* distribution, there seems to be little scope for Bertrand's Paradox here.  The distinction is that there is no "random chord": the question concerns two (presumably independent) random points within the annulus.